# Eclipse-RCP / SWT Preferences dialog apply button

Tags: eclipse-rcp

how can i add in SWT a SelectionListener to the default apply button in a preferences dialog?

Thanks!

Greets

Answer (score 4):

The PreferenceDialog has no apply Button. If you mean a PreferencePage you have to overwrite the `#applyData(Object)` method.